# Angular ui-router works fine in firefox but in chrome not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, web, angular-ui-router

I have simple angular ui router app:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('');
        $stateProvider
            .state('welcome', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'components/welcome/welcome.html',
                controller: 'MainController',
                data: {
                    auth: true
                }
            })
            .state('courses', {
                url: '/courses',
                templateUrl: 'components/courses/courses.html',
                controller: 'MainController',
                data: {
                    auth: true
                }

            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'components/login/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController',
                data: {
                    auth: false
                }
            })
    })
```

And when user first time go to browser execute this code:

```
.run(['$rootScope','$http', '$state', 'UserService','userEmailGetService','isUserLoggedService',
    function ( $rootScope,$http, $state, UserService,userEmailGetService,isUserLoggedService) {
        UserService.CheckIfLogged()
            .success(function(data) {
                userEmailGetService.setUserEmail(data.email);
                isUserLoggedService.setIsLogged(true);
                stateCallback();
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                isUserLoggedService.setIsLogged(false);
                stateCallback();
                $state.go("login");
            });
        this.stateCallback = function() {
            $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
                alert("Hello");
                if (toState.data.auth == true && !isUserLoggedService.getIsLogged()) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $state.go("login");
                }
                if (toState.data.auth == false && isUserLoggedService.getIsLogged()) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $state.go("welcome");
                }
            });
        };
    }])
```

Routing in Firefox works ok but in Chrome when I logged and I go to login section, browser should ban this redirect and go to welcome section, when I run programmer console in chrome and I redirect to login panel when I logged evrythink works correct, very strange for me. When I added alert in stateChangeStart firefox show me this alert, chrome not, only when I open programmer panel.

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Hi @Artur, any luck with getting your solution to work in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition as this is async:

```
UserService.CheckIfLogged()
    .success(function(data) {
        userEmailGetService.setUserEmail(data.email);
        isUserLoggedService.setIsLogged(true);
        stateCallback();
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        isUserLoggedService.setIsLogged(false);
        stateCallback();
        $state.go("login");
    });
```

This means that if the router is run before the validation code finishes, it will go to the login route instead of the welcome.
The solution is to use the resolve property of the routing, as it accepts promises, and will wait for the async response.

Comment: But this async code is run once when i load or reload page, problem is occurs when i change url from /courses to /login in browser url label

Comment: Yep, you're right - it should work. Try to capture $locationChangeStart, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`stateCallback` is not defined because you assigned this function to `this`. Remove `this` from declaration `this.stateCallback` and then this code should work.